# Arduino around the Xmega?

Tags: arduino-uno

I came across a dev board around the Atmel Xmega controller. This an AVR like used on Arduino, but with a lot of extras.

[image]

I was surprised to see that the board is hardly more expensive than an Arduino, despite:

> - 384kB of Flash (versus 32kB for Arduino)
> - DMA
> - Xmega can run at 32 MHz (16 MHz for Arduino)
> - on-board OLED display
> - on-board light and temperature sensors
> - on-board microSD socket

For all these on-board features you'd need a shield or breakout board for Arduino. I seems to me that for a lower price than Arduino you could build a much more powerful system, which is Arduino-compatible.
How hard would it be to port Arduino to the Xmega?

see also http://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-71436

Comment: [Eleventy-seven.](https://code.google.com/p/arduino/wiki/Platforms)

Comment: @Ignacio: thanks for that link. Not sure what eleventy-seven means, though. Is it slang for something?

Comment: It is a fictional arbitrary number.

Answer (score 1):

There's an attempt to get the Atmel XMEGA boards working in Arduino IDE.

https://github.com/akafugu/Xmegaduino

It's not fully featured yet but appears to have to features to allow you to start hacking with this board.